# Swift How to passing data over view controller using Segue?

Tags: swift, closures

I want to do like this
[image]

passing Data from A to C

like: keying some string in `A`, and click Button to `B`, then click Button to `C`.

show string in `C`'s Label

I find some passing Data like this

ex:

in `a`Class

`let bController = segue.destinationVieController`

`bController.string = "xxx"`

But it just A to B

What should I do to passing Data from `A` to `C` ?

Now, I use `NSNotificationCetner` to complete this work,but I want to learn how to use segue closure

If it's really easy, please tell me keyword

because I just search `A` to `B`...

thanks!

Comment: First you get string "xxx" on B right Now you same passing "xxx" B to C.

Comment: I have used NSUserDefaults to store values that are then available and updatable from any view. They also persist so if the app closes the next time you open the values available. This may be easier then passing values to the next view and then re-passing it onto the next

Answer (score 1):

You are passing string from A->B using segue, so you have the string now in Controller B. Pass the same string from B-> C using segue like below

```
let cController = segue.destinationVieController

cController.string = string
```

where string is the variable in Controller B which you have assigned value while segueing from A->B

Answer (score 0):

You can immediately perform the segue from b->c in prepare for segue

```
//VCA
override func prepareForSegue(segue : UISegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   if segue.identifier == "AtoB" {
      //Cast destination VC as a your B VC
      let bVC = segue.destinationViewController as! BVC 
      //Set b's .string property to the string property you're going to send to c
      bVC.string = self.string
      //perform the segue that goes from b to c
      bVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("BtoC")

   }

}
//VCB
override func prepareForSegue(segue : UISegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   if segue.identifier == "BtoC" {
      //Cast destination VC as a your C VC
      let cVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CVC 
      //Set c's .string property to the string property that you now go from 
      cVC.string = self.string

      //Now you will have segue'd to C passing the string you got from a
   }

}
```

Make sure that your `segue.identifier`'s match what you set them in storyboard.